# AJAX通信とapache httpd.confのkeepAlive設定について

Tags: apache, ajax

apacheのバージョンは2.0.64、MPMはpreforkの環境下にて、
httpd.confで下記の設定を行っています。

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers         5
MinSpareServers      5
MaxSpareServers     10
MaxClients         150
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

フロントからajaxでリクエストを連続で複数回投げた際に、
数回に1度の頻度で次のようなエラーが発生します。

PUTで204でレスポンスが返ってくるはずが、200でレスポンスが返され、
keepAliveTimeoutで設定した秒数の待機時間が発生します。

処理時間のタイムライン上、Content Downloadで待機するようです。

同一のブラウザから連続でリクエストを行っているのにkeepAlive設定の秒数の待機が発生するのは何故でしょうか。

また、keepAliveを無効にする、以外の解決策があればご教示頂けると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: チューニングに関する質問だと思いますが、一般的にボトルネックがどこかというのは総合的に検査していくものだと思いますのでいささか情報が足りないと感じます。apacheのバージョン、MPMの種類、その他のチューニングパラメータを追記出来ますか？サーバー再起動の直後でも再現しますか？それとも何度か使っていくうちに再現する感じでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。内容を追記しました。チューニング情報は関連あると思われるものを抜粋しましたが、その他必要な情報があれば再度ご指摘頂けるとありがたいです。サーバー再起動ですが、実行可能な環境にないため検証ができないのが現状です。

Comment: `ajax` `keepalive` で検索すると同様の事象の記事が色々出てきました。それらを読んだ限りブラウザやApacheの問題の可能性もあるので「チューニングに関する質問」だという私のコメントは取り下げます。失礼しました。

Comment: take88さんありがとうございます。

解決しましたので記載します。

今回使用していたajaxのリクエストでは、204ステータス(NO CONTENT)でレスポンスボディを含めて返却しており、そのレスポンスがGETとなり滞留していたようです。
今回の事象は、このレスポンスを削除することにより解決しました。

見当違いの視点からの質問で大変失礼しました。